# Them old shared server Rails deployment blues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Newb RoR developer here, standing at the finish line of my first paying Rails gig.  It's been fun, really, and I'm glad to have it over with so I can get on to using what I've learned on the next project.  The client already has their site up on a shared server at Network Solutions (go ahead, yuck it up), which professes to offer Ruby on Rails as a development solution.  Their version of Rails is a little out of date - 2.1.1 - and they are missing the only gem that I need for this project - AuthLogic.  I tried freezing the current (2.3.5) version of Rails into my app, only to be thwarted by a Passenger error telling me that NS's version of the Rack gem is still at 0.4.  I couldn't figure any way around that one, so I backed up and started over.

I then tried to use their 2.1.1 version of Rails and just add my application code, config files, lib folder, and vendor folder (and anything else I could think of, but that was about it).  I have tried AuthLogic as both a gem and as a plugin, updating the environment.rb file accordingly.  The gem approach told me that I was missing something but didn't even tell me what.  This was strange since I froze the gem (both installed *and* unpacked on my local machine) into the vendor folder.  The plugin approach seemed more logical since it's an older version of Rails at NS.  I get this :

undefined method `metaclass' for Authlogic::Session::Base:Class

So, what does that mean?  Isn't everything that's necessary supposed to be in the AuthLogic folder under vendor/plugins?  Is this a "brand new AuthLogic with old version of Rails" issue?

Here's the full URL : http://survey.plantright.org/account/new complete with gorgeous purple Passenger error stack.

Thanks in advance.

john

PS- I've had 3 tickets open with NS so far, begging them to update some of the gems on their system (Rack and Rails, and please install AuthLogic).  They haven't gotten back to me yet.  Go figure.

Comment: As long as NS offers `ruby` and `passenger` in their stack, you should be able to vendor everything else you need - including Rails and authlogic and all your other gems.

Comment: Indeed.  For some reason this does not seem to be the case over there.  The drop dead date is tomorrow, and I've given up waiting for NS support to answer my desperate pleas.  I started rewriting the entire thing in Drupal last night in a panic and discovered that brand of inspiration that only comes at the 11th hour.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issues with Dreamhost. There's a workaround for that here:
[Bypassing rack version error using Rails 2.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814856/bypassing-rack-version-error-using-rails-2-3-5)

It might work for you too.